# Refresh Razor view to UI Router $state

Tags: angularjs, razor, angular-ui-router

We have hybrid app were we have Razor views but we are setting up all the routing and behaviors with Angular and UI Router.
There are some cases were we POST something to the server but we are not being able to reload the `templateUrl` with UI Router.

We've tried using `$state.reload()`, `$state.transitonTo` and `$state.go` (both with `refresh: true`) but they won't ask the server to reload the view back to us.

Is there any way we can ask the server to reload this Razor view and then reload it on the angular side?

Thanks!

Comment: need to be a lot more specific than `can't reload templateUrl`. Provide reference code and better explanation

Comment: I need to ask the server again to render the view, it might have something to do with angular template cache.

Comment: are you changing template in back end? Server doesn't render view, angular does

Comment: That's the point, our Views ar Razor .cshtml files that are rendered on the server. I call them using the templateUrl in ui-router with the URL that .net gives us for those same templates. For example the templateUrl for "home" is /Home and the real file in the backend is home.cshtml

Comment: but are you changing them dynamically at server? Still not clear what the specific problem is and you haven't provided any code

Comment: yes, it's changing dynamically, I've added the answer, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer here is `$templateCache.remove`.
It'll force the cache to be removed from the desired template.

Our problem is that the template is being reloaded in the server based in `http.post` from a modal window, and angular had no way of knowing that.

So we changed this:

```
http.post(controllerUrl, payload).success(function(result) {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    window.location.reload();
});
```

to this:

```
http.post(controllerUrl, payload).success(function(result) {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    templateCache.remove('/home');
    state.reload();
});
```